# linked-list interview question

Tags: java, linked-list

This was the question asked in interview.Can anybody help me out it in implementing in java
**Given 2 linked lists(which need not have unique elements) *find intersection point* in the form of Y.(it can be anywhere--middle or tail)**

Comment: By intersection point do they mean where a group elements intersect, or just a single element overlap?

Comment: Please show how you approached the problem and where you are puzzled (in this case, it may be that you haven't thought of a good algorithm).  I'd rather you either asked for an algorithm or showed difficulties you were having in implementing it in Java.

Comment: @justkt: The only way the two linked lists could have a single element overlap is if they intersect at the tail of both lists.

Comment: i didnt think of good algorithm .

Comment: @Jason, I don't follow; could you provide details?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as java ?

Comment: Do we know that there is an intersection?

Comment: @Riduidel, OP is requesting an implementation in Java.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus:  You have to think in terms of the references.  A node in a linked list contains a reference to the next node in the list.  If the two lists do merge then all the references in the rest of the list *must* be the same.  There are two ways that the lists can have only 1 node in common.  1: Each list has a single node that's that is the same node 2: Each list's final node is the same.

Comment: @giri, have the two answers below helped you?  If not, please edit your question to define "intersection point" and "Y" for us; I'm not willing to provide an answer because I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: @Jason, why are you assuming that the lists are being merged or that they have only one node in common?

Comment: @Lord Torgamus:  Maybe I'm misunderstanding @giri's question (which is why I haven't posted an answer), but the intersection point of two linked lists sounds like the node at which the two linked lists merge.

Comment: @Jason, we're in the same boat then; I guess I was wondering if you knew a formal definition I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus:  I don't consider the request for a Java implementation well suited for SO.  The question about the algorithm certainly is, and if the OP had a stab at a Java implementation it would be.

Comment: @David, I assume you're referring to my earlier comment to Riduidel; I'm not attempting to defend the OP there, merely answering Riduidel's question.

Comment: @Lord Torgaumus (c. 11:44 CDT or 18:44 GMT):  You are correct; I didn't specify which comment I was replying to, and probably should have.

Answer (score 6):

If the length of the lists is `O(N)`, this solution is `O(N)` with `O(1)` space.

```
FUNCTION length(LIST list) : INT
// returns number of nodes until the end of the list

FUNCTION skip(LIST list, INT k) : LIST
// return the sublist of list, skipping k nodes

FUNCTION intersection(LIST list1, list2) : LIST
// returns the sublist where the two lists intersects
  INT n1 = length(list1);
  INT n2 = length(list2);

  IF (n1 > n2) THEN
     list1 = skip(list1, n1-n2)
  ELSE
     list2 = skip(list2, n2-n1)

  WHILE (list1 != list2)
    list1 = skip(list1, 1)
    list2 = skip(list2, 1)

  RETURN list1
```

Essentially, traverse each lists to find how many nodes there are. Then, skip enough elements from the longer list so that now you have lists of the same length. Then, in-sync, move forward step-by-step until the two lists meet.

Comment: @polygenelubricants, how is this O(n) ? List comparison would be O(n) and you are doing this up to n times. For example run the above code with the lists {1,2,3,4} and {1,2,3,5}

Comment: Smart. @Jasmeet, `list1 != list2` is just doing an O(1) comparison of the addresses of these two list nodes, not performing an element-by-element comparison, so overall it is O(n). The key insight is that the intersection point must be the same distance from the end in both lists, so comparing corresponding elements is enough to find it.

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

I don't have a good example at the moment, but I believe he's referring to this:

"The intersection of two sets is the set containing only the elements common to both sets."

Where 'sets' can also be Lists, etc.

Java has built in methods for this.

Say you have a List list, you would do something like this:

list.removeAll(list2);

or

list.retainAll(list2);

retainAll will you give you the 'intersection', removeAll gives you the difference between the two lists.

Comment: But then, what's the point part?  I think he's underspecified the problem.

Comment: I may have over-simplified his question in an effort to clarify. Perhaps it's a bit more complex given the 'point' part.

Answer (score 1):

According to @Lord Torgamus question, here is a suggested **java** algorithm.

Suppose you have two java [Collection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) objects (and [LinkedList](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), as an implementor of [List](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html), is also an implementor of Collection). To find their intersection, you only have to call [Collection#retainAll](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method on the first object giving the second one as an argument.